# AsyncTask - long time between returning from doInBackground and execution of onPostExecute (with PagerAdapter)

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm using AsyncTask to download images from the Internet. I'm showing them in ViewPager.

I call it from `instantiateItem` method in `MyPagerAdapter` using:

```
downloader.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,imageView, url);
```

My downloader looks like:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {

        //(...)
        //downloading image using httpConnection and decoding it to bitmap using BitmapFactory
        //(...)

        Log.d("myApp", "returning");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return bitmap;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long period = stop-start;
        Log.d("myApp-trace","it took: "+period);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }
```

The problem is, it takes about ~2000 miliseconds between returing from doInBackground and entering onPostExecute.

What is strange, when I swipe the ViewPager later (after the first images are loaded) it works normally and takes ~0-5 miliseconds.

Do you have any ideas what can it be caused by?

Comment: how big are these images? are they being cached? are you calling execute from the viewpager?

Comment: I don't know why size of images or caching them matters. Downloading them is not a problem and works fast (They're about 200kB jpgs, They're not cached). I just have problem with long time after the image is downloaded to enter onPostExecute (it only happens at the beginning). 

As I said, I call execute from instantiateItem method in MyPagerAdapter.

Comment: It because you block main thread in some other place. Fx in instantiateItem after execute call... Calls on main thread are queued so onPostExecute has to have wait for its turn...

Comment: I don't know when it could be blocked.
Calling execute is the last thing done in instantiateItem.
Setting adapter is the last thing made in onCreateView in Activity
There should really be nothing done on UI thread as I know. How can I check what's going on? I've tried using DDMS method profiling, but I only get methods from Android SDK which say nothing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution. The problem was in Fragments - when I was starting new activity with ViewPager, it took a lot of time to save old fragments' bundles (there was a list of many objects as Serializable). I noticed that by looking into DDMS method profiling. There was no my own methods, so I thought it may be something with fragments operations.